How to average camera extrinsics each calculated from a target detected at different angles?
Let's say I have a given number n of cameras with known intrinsics. Each camera is synchronized, and each camera detected t frames with a calibration target that was rotated and moved around, seen simultaneously by every camera.
For each frame, I have some objp, imgp, where imgp are detected points of the calibration target. I am using them to compute extrinsics [R|t] (with cv2.solvePnP.)
How do I average together all this data? If I understand correctly, I can't simply do quaternion averaging and translation averaging on the raw results of cv2.solvePnP, since - as the target is rotated and moved around - the frame of reference will be different.
I tried changing the frame of reference first, like shown below:
def get_extrinsics_fixed_to_global_reference(R_ref, t_ref, R_other, t_other):

    # Get the extrinsics of the other camera in the reference camera's coordinate system
    R = R_other @ R_ref.T
    t = t_other - R @ t_ref

    return R, t

but I got garbage results. I am currently using a setup with n = 2 cameras.
Edit: To clarify, my idea was to essentially compare the resulting transformations between the coordinate systems of cam_0 and cam_k for k > 0. For each set of frames (corresponding to a calibration target tilted in a specific way) I would get a set of said transformations (cam_0 -> cam_k), and they should be in theory the same - this is where I would average out the rotation matrices to then finally get extrinsics. Note: I already know intrinsics for each camera.
Edit 2: I think I fixed it, below is a visualization of what I meant:


I am skeptical of averaging any intrinsics. each lens may have different (true) intrinsics. are you even speaking of intrinsics? you speak of frames. that's not intrinsics.

what's your goal? You have n different cameras with n different intrinsics? What do you want to do with the cameras? Why do you want to average the extrinsics? Do you want to perform a 3D reconstruction of a scene? Every extrinsic belongs to a single frame-camera-combination, so I don't know what kind of sense it makes to even try to average them.

@ChristophRackwitz it is literally in the title. I have good intrinsics for every camera already.

@Micka I just thought that using multiple such frame-camera-combinations would help me get better extrinsics than from a single frame (for each camera). My idea was to get multiple transformations  between camera 0 and other cameras, computed by different frames (since in theory these transformations should be the same) and use these to somehow enhance extrinsics

@Micka and @ ChristophRackwitz, thank you for your answers, I updated the post with a clarification

Ok, so there are n stationery caneras and they capture images time-synchronized (which accuracy? 5 ms or 1 ms or 50 us?) The pattern moves , ok. You get extrinsics per position per cam. What's the target value now that you want to find? Do you want to find the camera positions relative to each other?

Yes, since with transformations between camera coordinate systems  I could perform triangulation. But when I average these transformations, I imagine the triangulation will be more accurate, if I am thinking correctly

@Micka The accuracy is 20ms

Try inverting the object pose to get the camera pose relative to the marker. And not the poses should he constant, but the relative positions between the cameras. Tey measuring cam1pos - cam2pos without regarding the rotation at all in the beginning. Once you can confirm this makes more sense you can think about the rotations.

I think you are operating under a fundamental misunderstanding: statistics provide useful metrics to evaluate the performance of a computer vision algorithm after one has implemented the algorithm. They are not, in general, a part of the algorithm.
In your case, the statistic you mention is some sort of "average", and the system a calibrated multi-camera rig and associated software. Just averaging a collection of partial calibration data you have computed won't generally improve your performance, because the performance goal is obtained by computing an optimum (namely, the set of extrinsic parameters that minimize the reprojection errors), not by running a poll asking each camera what it thinks the solution is. There is an underlying physical truth your are trying to discover, not an election to win.
The correct way to improve the accuracy of the extrinsic calibration of your multi-camera setup it is to merge all the data you have collected (the target point coordinates) into a single dataset, and then run a global bundle adjustment procedure on it.
See, for more info:

Old but still good: Bill Triggs's review of bundle adjustment
Software:Ceres solver


Thank you for your answer. So is the average of extrinsics meaningless? In my intuition, with sufficiently large number of frames the average of extrinsics would converge to the true physical position of the camera. Maybe averaging extrinsics would at least provide a heuristic for an initial guess for bundle adjustment?

Ask yourself: average under what probability distribution? Meaning: what is the statistical model of the errors?

I understand I am treating the problem as running a poll querying each set of frames to give me a transformation from 0-th to i-th camera, assuming e.g. distance from predicted to true image points is a 2D normal distribution, for instance ignoring camera synchronization. But aren't these assumptions a similiar sin to (for example) assume cv2.findChessboard is approximately correct? I understand BA is the way to go, but I still can't imagine average of extrinsics not converging to true extrinsics.

No, the assumptions are not similar at all. Computing a simple arithmetic average of model parameters is not the same thing as estimating said parameters using a model-fitting procedure under explicitly stated assumption about the error distribution. Please read the reference I gave you above, or similar one.  You need to do some homework in order to know how to ask well-posed questions.
